# Any other compound words with opposite meanings like "bittersweet"?

Tags: compound-words

I was curious if there were other words like "bittersweet". To clarify, I'm interested in compound words where the 2 sub-words' meanings are opposites.

Is "bittersweet" unusual in this respect? I can't think of any other words with this characteristic.

Comment: [Chiaroscuro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiaroscuro) is a loanword from Italian used in English.

Comment: cf. "curvilinear" -- this 'linear' means 'thin', not 'straight'.  'Bitter' and 'sweet' are not polar opposites.

Comment: Shouldn't the proper time to close questions be: before they've received answers? This one sat open for four days before being closed.

Comment: As Aml says, "bitter" and "sweet" are not opposites.

Comment: @Bread - The proper time to close a question is when it receives enough close votes.  One could argue that a different scheme should be used, but that's a topic for Meta.

Comment: Thank you. I took it to meta and was nicely informed there, as here. I apologize here, as I did there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several lists online. Here are some examples

> spendthrift - the first part "spend" is the true meaning
>
> bridegroom - the second part "groom" is the true meaning

taken from http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/archive/index.php/t-130911.html

Etymologically [oxymoron](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oxymoron) fits this pattern too.

Comment: Tracked another source list for these one word oxymorons. http://www.lingerandlook.com/Words/Oxymora.htm#one

Answer (score -2):

I would like to offer one possibility: lampshade.

Comment: Or even 'lightshade'. (+1).